# If $AB=0$ for two commuting linear operators and their kernels intersect trivially, do they span the whole vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

$\DeclareMathOperator{Ker}{Ker}\DeclareMathOperator{Im}{Im}$
In the finite dimensional case, this is clear by counting dimensions: The image of $B$ must lie completely in the kernel of $A$, and thus we have

$$
V \simeq \Im B \oplus \Ker B\leq \Ker A \oplus \Ker B
$$

And in the finite dimensional case, we can verify because of the trivial intersection that $V$ and $\Ker A +\Ker B$ have the same dimension, thus must be equal.

However, is there a way to conclude this in the infinite dimensional case? Just because $V\simeq U \oplus W$ for two trivially intersecting spaces does not necessarily imply that: Consider for instance $k^\mathbb ℤ$ for some field $k$ and $U$ taking components $(1,\infty)$ and $W$ components $(-\infty,-1)$. The zeroth component is missing in their span.

However, can we fix that in our special case of two commuting operators whose product vanishes on the *entire* space?

As @Servaes correctly pointed out, it is not true if our operators do not commute. But what if they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true. Let $A, B: k^{\mathbf{N}} \to k^{\mathbf{N}}$ be $\DeclareMathOperator{Ker}{Ker}$
$$A:(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)\mapsto (0,x_1,0,x_2,0,x_4,0,x_6,\cdots),
$$
$$B: (x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)\mapsto (0,0,x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,\cdots).
$$
Then, $AB=BA =0$, but $\Im A +\Im B = \Ker B + \Ker A = \langle e_2,e_3,e_4,\cdots \rangle < k^{\mathbf{N}}.$

Answer (score 1):

No; let $k$ be a field and $V=k^{\Bbb{N}}$, and consider the linear maps $A,B:\ V\ \longmapsto\ V$ given by
$$A((x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}})_m=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x_m&\ \text{ if }\ m\ \text{ is odd}\\
0&\ \text{ if }\ m\ \text{ is even}
\end{array}\right..$$
$$B((x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}})_m=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0&\ \text{ if }\ m\ \text{ is odd}\\
x_{m/2}&\ \text{ if }\ m\ \text{ is even}
\end{array}\right..$$
Then $\ker B=0$ so the kernels intersect trivially, and $AB=0$. But $A\neq0$ so $\ker A+\ker B\neq V$.

More legibly; the linear maps $A$ and $B$ are defined as
$$A(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,\ldots)=(0,x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,0,\ldots),$$
$$B(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,\ldots)=(x_0,0,x_1,0,x_2,0,x_3,\ldots).$$

Comment: Don't you mean $x_{m-1}$ for $B$? I presume you want to map the odd ones to the even ones which are projected to $0$ by $A$ afterwards. Also note that $\ker B$ is not trivial, as it forgets all odd coordinates.

Comment: That's a bit problematic for $m=0$, and you then lose the fact that $\ker B$ which makes the whole problem a lot easier.

Comment: But as you currently wrote it, $B$ maps $e_6\mapsto e_3$ which does not lie in the kernel of $A$, so $AB \neq 0.$

Comment: No, it maps $e_3$ to $e_6$; all odd coordinates in the image of $B$ are $0$, so $e_3$ cannot be in it. I've edited to clarify the notation.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for your clarifications. But in this case, $BA \neq 0$, so they don't commute. Perhaps I should edit my question as this is what I'm interested in.